# Convert True/False value read from file to boolean

Tags: python, string, boolean

I'm reading a `True - False` value from a file and I need to convert it to boolean. Currently it always converts it to `True` even if the value is set to `False`.

Here's a `MWE` of what I'm trying to do:

```
with open('file.dat', mode="r") as f:
    for line in f:
        reader = line.split()
        # Convert to boolean <-- Not working?
        flag = bool(reader[0])

if flag:
    print 'flag == True'
else:
    print 'flag == False'
```

The `file.dat` file basically consists of a single string with the value `True` or `False` written inside. The arrangement looks very convoluted because this is a minimal example from a much larger code and this is how I read parameters into it.

Why is `flag` always converting to `True`?

Comment: pip install [str2bool](https://github.com/symonsoft/str2bool)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`bool('True')` and `bool('False')` always return `True` because strings 'True' and 'False' are not empty.

To quote a great man (and Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)):

> #### [5.1. Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition  or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The
>   following values are considered false:
>
> - …
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - …
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types
>   are always true.

The built-in [`bool`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) function uses the standard truth testing procedure. That's why you're always getting `True`.

To convert a string to boolean you need to do something like this:

```
def str_to_bool(s):
    if s == 'True':
         return True
    elif s == 'False':
         return False
    else:
         raise ValueError # evil ValueError that doesn't tell you what the wrong value was
```

Comment: You could make it a "heroic" `ValueError` by doing `raise ValueError("Cannot covert {} to a bool".format(s))`.

Comment: Selecting this one since it uses no extra packages. Thanks guys!

Comment: What's wrong with "extra packages"?  Are you referring to `ast`?  It's part of the standard library, so it's not really extra.

Comment: it might be a silly question but why does `bool` just not convert the strings `True` and `False` to the boolean values `True` and `False`? Seems to be inconsistent behaviour from what `int` does. I just genuinely curious why my reasoning is wrong and why the other option was the decision.

Comment: Whenever comparing strings I like to flatten the case, (where applicable). for example I would use:
if s.upper() == 'TRUE':
    return True
elif s.upper() == 'FALSE'
    return False

Answer (score 92):

you can use [`distutils.util.strtobool`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool)

```
>>> from distutils.util import strtobool

>>> strtobool('True')
1
>>> strtobool('False')
0
```

`True` values are `y`, `yes`, `t`, `true`, `on` and `1`; `False` values are `n`, `no`, `f`, `false`, `off` and `0`. Raises `ValueError` if **val** is anything else.

Comment: Even better, do `bool(strtobool(my_string))` to cast the output as a boolean True / False variable

Comment: @AlexG crazy that a function called `strtobool()` does not, in fact, return a `bool`

Comment: Note that `distutils` is deprecated and will be removed in Python 3.12.

Answer (score 62):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('True')
True
>>> ast.literal_eval('False')
False
```

> Why is flag always converting to True?

Non-empty strings are always True in Python.

Related: [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

---

If NumPy is an option, then:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = 'True - False - True'
>>> c = StringIO.StringIO(s)
>>> np.genfromtxt(c, delimiter='-', autostrip=True, dtype=None) #or dtype=bool
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: it might be a silly question but why does `bool` just not convert the strings `True` and `False` to the boolean values `True` and `False`? Seems to be inconsistent behaviour from what `int` does. I just genuinely curious why my reasoning is wrong and why the other option was the decision.

Comment: ast.literal_eval('false') throws an exception, which I think makes it less desirable

Comment: @Chris You can always wrap it around try-except in a custom function instead of using it directly then.

Comment: @HewwoCraziness It parses only expressions not any random code.

Answer (score 22):

The cleanest solution that I've seen is:

```
from distutils.util import strtobool
def string_to_bool(string):
    return bool(strtobool(str(string)))
```

Sure, it requires an import, but it has proper error handling and requires very little code to be written (and tested).

Comment: This doesn't work unless the input value can actually be a boolean, otherwise, it seems to throw a value error. The only thing I can think of is to add a try/except to your function and on `ValueError` return false.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not suggested this as the best answer, just an alternative but you can also do something like:

```
flag = reader[0] == "True"
```

flag will be `True` id reader[0] is "True", otherwise it will be `False`.

Answer (score 15):

Currently, it is evaluating to `True` because the variable has a value. There is a [good example found here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/boolean.html) of what happens when you evaluate arbitrary types as a boolean.

In short, what you want to do is isolate the `'True'` or `'False'` string and run `eval` on it.

```
>>> eval('True')
True
>>> eval('False')
False
```

Comment: @samyi It is dangerous to use the eval method.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Comment: FYI. This is a terrible idea and you should *never* use `eval()`. In my opinion, it should be removed from the language.

Comment: This is VERY VERY BAD because it is a security flaw. If you use `eval()` on raw data from a file then it means that anyone with write access to that file can execute code at the same permissions level as your script.

Comment: Additionally, if values have not the exact python spelling, e.g. `eval('false')`, `eval('FALSE')` it will error.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to be case-insensitive, you can just do:

```
b = True if bool_str.lower() == 'true' else False
```

Example usage:

```
>>> bool_str = 'False'
>>> b = True if bool_str.lower() == 'true' else False
>>> b
False
>>> bool_str = 'true'
>>> b = True if bool_str.lower() == 'true' else False
>>> b
True
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use dict to convert string to boolean. Change this line `flag = bool(reader[0])` to:

```
flag = {'True': True, 'False': False}.get(reader[0], False) # default is False
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do with `json`.

```
In [124]: import json

In [125]: json.loads('false')
Out[125]: False

In [126]: json.loads('true')
Out[126]: True
```

Comment: This gives a JSON Decode Error when the string is 'True' or 'False' i.e. title-format. Use json.loads('False'.lower) in that case.

Answer (score 4):

### pip install [str2bool](https://github.com/symonsoft/str2bool)

```
>>> from str2bool import str2bool
>>> str2bool('Yes')
True
>>> str2bool('FaLsE')
False
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data is from json, you can do that

> import json
>
> json.loads('true')
>
> True

Answer (score 4):

Just to add that if your truth value can vary, for instance if it is an input from different programming languages or from different types, a more robust method would be:

```py
flag = value in ['True','true',1,'T','t','1'] # this can be as long as you want to support
```

And a more performant variant would be (set lookup is O(1)):

```py
TRUTHS = set(['True','true',1,'T','t','1'])
flag = value in truths
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `strtobool` is now deprecated.

Here is an implementation based on configparser which you can use instead of your `bool`:

```
import configparser

def strtobool(s):
    try:
        return configparser.ConfigParser.BOOLEAN_STATES[s.lower()]
    except KeyError as e:
        raise ValueError('Not a boolean: %s' % s) from e
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need quick way to convert strings into bools (that functions with most strings) try.

```
def conv2bool(arg):
   try:
     res= (arg[0].upper()) == "T"
   except Exception,e:
     res= False
   return res # or do some more processing with arg if res is false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dicts to convert "True" in True:

```py
def str_to_bool(s: str):
    status = {"True": True,
                "False": False}
    try:
        return status[s]
    except KeyError as e:
        #logging
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
>>> my_value = "False"
```

then either do

```
>>> my_value in "False"
True
>>> my_value in "True"
False
```

or

```
>>> "False" in my_value
True
>>> "True" in my_value
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def strtobool(val):
    """Convert a string representation of truth to true (1) or false (0).
    True values are 'y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', and '1'; false values
    are 'n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', and '0'.  Raises ValueError if
    'val' is anything else.
    """
    val = val.lower()
    if val in ('y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', '1'):
        return True
    elif val in ('n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', '0'):
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid truth value %r" % (val,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator one-liner:

```
var_x = True if str_x == 'True' else False
```