# Check value of unicode True or False Python

Tags: python, unicode, boolean

I have a unicode variable called uploaded. It is a unicode and is retrieved from web request. it's value is either `u'True`or `u'False`. I need to check it's value to see if it's true or false but `if uploaded:` always evaluates to True. What's the best way of checking this in python?

Comment: What about `if uploaded == u"True"`?

Comment: This answer might be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732123/convert-true-false-value-read-from-file-to-boolean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a string value, you'll need to see if the literal text `'True'` is contained in that string:

```
if uploaded == u'True':
```

Any non-empty string object is considered true in a truth test, so the *string* `u'False'` is true too!

Alternatively, you could use the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to interpret the string contents as a Python literal; this would also support other types:

```
import ast

if ast.literal_eval(uploaded):
```

`ast.literal_eval(u'True')` would return the actual boolean `True` object, `ast.literal_eval(u'False')` would give you the actual `False` value.